# How to write data to excel file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a config table as below:

```
S.NO    TableName   SourceColumns 
1          A         a,b,c,d 
2          B         p,q,r,s,t,u 
3          C         m,n,o,p,q 
4          D         x,y,z
```

Here, result object consists of SourceColumns of each record from the table.
For instance, here it gets the 1 record values. Then I am writing those values to CSV(excel) file. This works.

```
CSV.open('C:\Actual\Test.csv', 'w') do |csv| 
   result.each do |eachrow| 
   csv << ["#{eachrow['a']}","#{eachrow['b']}","#{eachrow['c']}","#{eachrow['d']}"] 
  end
end
```

As, I have hardcoded my values in the above query, I am constructing the string per my SourceColumns and passing to query as below:

```
myformattedstring="#{eachrow['a']}","#{eachrow['b']}","#{eachrow['c']}","#{eachrow['d']}" 

CSV.open('C:\Actual\Test.csv', 'w') do |csv| 
   result.each do |eachrow| 
   csv << [myformattedstring] 
   end 
end
```

Now, the data is being treated as string. How, can i pass my string to the CSV so that I can write the actual values

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is `myformattedstring`? What do you mean by *"its corresponding values are not reflected"*? What *are* the values, and what result *do* you get?

Comment: I have a config table as below:
S.NO TableName SourceColumns
1  A   a,b,c,d
2  B   p,q,r,s,t,u
3  C   m,n,o,p,q
4  D   x,y,z

>CSV.open('C:\Actual\Test.csv', 'w') do |csv|
 >result.each do |eachrow|
  >csv << ["#{eachrow['a']}","#{eachrow['b']}","#{eachrow['c']}","#{eachrow['d']}"]
 >end
>end

I am constructing the string per my source columns and passing to query
myformattedstring="#{eachrow['a']}","#{eachrow['b']}","#{eachrow['c']}","#{eachrow['d']}"

CSV.open('C:\Actual\Test.csv', 'w') do |csv|
 result.each do |eachrow|
  csv << [myformattedstring]
 end
end

Comment: Can you please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50579281/edit) to include all important information, properly formatted. That comment is extremely difficult to read.

Comment: Updated in the actual query

Comment: Your question is still not entirely clear, because I don't know how to **reproduce** it. When you say "I have a config table", what exactly does that mean? What format is that data in? How are you reading it with the ruby script? Moreover, in your code sample you use the variable `result` (which is crucial to your question), yet you never show us what `result` is actually equal to!

Comment: The main point to your question, I think, is that you want to programatically fetch values like `eachrow['a']` rather than hardcoding stings like `'a'`. Perhaps all you need to do is: `csv << eachrow.values`?? If this is the case, then the variable is confusingly named.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert only 1 column in your csv containing `myformattedstring`, you need to put the double quotes only at the beginning and the end of your string, and interpolate all the `#{}` inside those quotes, as opposed to repeating the quotes